# Error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: uknown error (code 0)

Tags: image, sqlite, listview, fragment

I have existing ListView which filled with some information from SQLite database. I want to store and retrieve images from SQLite database then show it in ListView. I had already build Databasehandler and Adapter for that. But, the problem is when I run my project it get uknown error (code 0): Native could not create new byte[].

-Logcat

```
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Native could not create new byte[]
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:399)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at kre.db.DatabaseHandler.getAllCard(DatabaseHandler.java:275)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.example.kre.MyWallet.onActivityCreated(MyWallet.java:58)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-10 00:32:24.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

-MyWallet

```
package com.example.kre;

import kre.adapter.ListAdapterMyWallet;
import kre.db.DatabaseHandler;
import kre.model.Card;
import kre.model.Category;

import com.example.login.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyWallet extends Fragment {

    public MyWallet(){}

    ArrayList<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
    List<Category> listCategory;
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapterMyWallet adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mywallet, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());      

        /*listCategory = db.getAllCategory();
        if(listCategory.size()==0)
        {
            db.addCategory(new Category("Food"));
            db.addCategory(new Category("Shopping"));
            db.addCategory(new Category("Health"));
            listCategory = db.getAllCategory();
        }*/
        List<Card> cards = db.getAllCard();
        if(cards.size() == 0)
        {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
            db.addCard(new Card(imageInByte, "Pizza Hut", 0));
        }
        for(Card cd : cards){
            String log =  "ID: " + cd.getId() + "Image: " + cd.getCardImg() + "Name: " + cd.getCardName()  
                    + "Card Type Id: " + cd.getCardTypeId();
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            cardList.add(cd);
        }

        adapter = new ListAdapterMyWallet(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row_mywallet, cardList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

-ListAdapterMyWallet

```
package kre.adapter;

import kre.model.Card;
import com.example.login.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapterMyWallet extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<Card> cardItems = new ArrayList<Card>();

        public ListAdapterMyWallet(Context context, int layoutResourceId ,ArrayList<Card> cardItems) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, cardItems);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.cardItems = cardItems;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            CardHolder holder = null;

            if(row==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new CardHolder();
                holder.txtCardName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.card_img);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }else
            {
                holder = (CardHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            Card card = cardItems.get(position);
            holder.txtCardName.setText(card.getCardName());
            //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

            byte[] outImage=card.getCardImg();
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
           return row;
        }

        static class CardHolder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;
            TextView txtCardName;
        }
    }
```

-DatabaseHandler

```
package kre.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import kre.model.Profile;
import kre.model.Card;
import kre.model.Category;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "KRE";

    //Table names
    private static final String TABLE_PROFILE = "profile";
    private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "category";
    private static final String TABLE_CARD = "card";

    //Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT ="created_at";

    //Profile column names
    private static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";

    //Category column names
    private static final String KEY_CATEGORY ="category";

    //Card column names
    private static final String KEY_CARD_IMG = "card_img";
    private static final String KEY_CARD_NAME = "card_name";
    private static final String KEY_CARD_TYPE_ID ="card_type_id";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //Category table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORY
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    //Card table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CARD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARD
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_CARD_IMG + " BLOB," +
            KEY_CARD_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_CARD_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    //Profile table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROFILE + 
            "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_IMG + " BLOB," + 
            KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT" + ")";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CARD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVesion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_PROFILE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_CARD);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Profile
    public void addProfile(Profile profile){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMG, profile.getImg());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, profile.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, profile.getPhone());

        db.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Profile getProfile(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PROFILE, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_IMG, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE}, 
        KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Profile profile = new Profile(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getBlob(1),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
        return profile;
    }

    public List<Profile> getAllProfile(){
        List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROFILE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                Profile profile = new Profile();
                profile.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                profile.setImg(cursor.getBlob(1));
                profile.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
                profile.setName(cursor.getString(3));
                profile.setPhone(cursor.getString(4));
                profileList.add(profile);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return profileList;
    }

    public int getProfileCounts(){
        int count = 0;
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROFILE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int updateProfile(Profile profile){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMG, profile.getImg());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, profile.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, profile.getPhone());

        return db.update(TABLE_PROFILE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(profile.getID())});
    }

    public void updatePicture(byte[] imageInByte, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String strSQL = "UPDATE profile SET img = '"+imageInByte+"' WHERE id = " +id+"";
        db.execSQL(strSQL);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteProfile(Profile profile){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_PROFILE, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(profile.getID())});
        db.close();
    }

    //Category
    public void addCategory(Category category){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category.getCategory());
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        db.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Category getCategory(int id) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

         Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CATEGORY, new String[] { KEY_ID,
          KEY_CATEGORY}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
         if (cursor != null)
             cursor.moveToFirst();

         Category category = new Category(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
          cursor.getString(1));
         // return contact
         return category;
    }

    public List<Category> getAllCategory(){
        List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                category.setCategory(cursor.getString(1));
                category.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(2));
                categoryList.add(category);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return categoryList;
    }

     public int updateCategory(Category category) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category.getCategory());

         return db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(category.getId())});
     }

    public void deleteCategory(Category category) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         db.delete(TABLE_CATEGORY, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(category.getId())});
         db.close();
    }

    public int getCategoryCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Card
    public void addCard(Card card){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CARD_IMG, card.getCardImg());
        values.put(KEY_CARD_NAME, card.getCardName());
        values.put(KEY_CARD_TYPE_ID, Integer.toString(card.getCardTypeId()));
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        db.insert(TABLE_CARD, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Card> getAllCardWithCategory(int categoryId){
        List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARD + " WHERE " + KEY_CARD_TYPE_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(categoryId) + ";";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Card card = new Card();
                card.setCardId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                card.setCardImg(cursor.getBlob(1));
                card.setCardName(cursor.getString(2));
                card.setCardTypeId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                card.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(4));
                cardList.add(card);
            }while(cursor.moveToLast());
        }
        return cardList;
    }

    public List<Card> getAllCard(){
        List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARD;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Card card = new Card();
                card.setCardId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                card.setCardImg(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARD_IMG)));
                card.setCardName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARD_NAME)));
                card.setCardTypeId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARD_TYPE_ID))));
                card.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
                cardList.add(card);
            }while(cursor.moveToLast());
        }
        return cardList;
    }

    //getDateTime function
    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

when I delete db.addCard method, my program work, but i can't add images into database. Another fragment of my program is to store profile picture and information, whether this is due to lack of memory?

Sorry for my bad English, any help is welcome! Thanks